# How to send AWS Chime Meeting events to EventBridge?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge, aws-chime-sdk, amazon-chime

I have a default Event Bus. I created a rule for AWS Chime events and added a trigger.

I was able to get S3 Events go to EventBridge. There is a setting under bucket properties to do so. However, I am not able to find such setting for Chime SDK.

I looked up in all the documentation available. Please let me know if anyone knows where to enable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Chime does not have a setting to send Events to Event Bridge. It happens by default.

I just needed to create an Event Rule in the right region; which is the Chime API endpoint region and not the media region.

In my case I was listening for pattern rule in Asia Pacific(Mumbai) but needed to be done on US East(Virginia)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a media pipeline and record the meeting you can trigger events based off the data that gets stored in s3. Alternatively, you can write custom events and publish them yourself wherever you're using the amazon chime sdk, that's what I've done for creating meeting related events.

Comment: Try with API region events will be sent to default eventbus